# Laravel 4 alpha_dash validation odd issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel 4, validation. The following passes validation even though the username input field contains invalid characters of "đšđšžšđčč". Why is that? Should not alpha_dash allow only '/^([a-z0-9_-])+$/i'?

```
public function postSignup()
{
    $data = Input::all();

    $validator = Validator::make(
        $data,
        array('username' => 'required|alpha_dash')
    );

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        echo 'fail';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ok';
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're experiencing is acceptable behavior for the Validator class. Here's the rule's exact code (at the time of this writing):

```
return preg_match('/^[\pL\pN_-]+$/u', $value);
```

The `u` modifier at the end [enables UTF-8 support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). `\pL` and `\pN` are then [unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) which match letters and numbers respectively (similar to `\w` and `\d` that you may already be used to).

I don't know exactly what data you're validating against, but UTF-8 support is a good thing to have in your application. That said, if you'd like to create your own rule that is more tailored, [`Validator::extend()`](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules) is perfect for it.

Comment: Thanks, apparently online API docs were not up to date. While UTF-8 support is good thing, sometimes accepting only a-z0-9 may be preferred, like for usernames.

Comment: Yup -- use whatever validation is necessary for that part of your application. Sometimes that means UTF-8, others not so much.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about this but you may register a custom validation rule to allow only `ascii` characters

```
Validator::extend('asciiOnly', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return !preg_match('/[^x00-x7F]/i', $value);
});
```

So, you can use something like this

```
array('username' => 'required|asciiOnly|alpha_dash');
```

It may work to disallow/invalidate non-ascii characters (`not tested`).